# Unable to show the action bar with SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar

I am unable to show the action bar when SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE is used as following:

```
getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
                 View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE);
```

I use getSupportActionBar().show() and getSupportActionBar().hide() to show or hide the action bar.  If SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE is taken out from the above code, everything will be fine - the action bar can be shown or hid without any problem.
Could anyone shed some light on this?